# GeoServer first filter does not work

Tags: geoserver, sld

I've cerated SLD style and send to the GeoServer. But after sending just **the second filter works**!

SLD in GeoServer is like this :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sld:StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.0.0">
  <sld:NamedLayer>
    <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
    <sld:UserStyle>
      <sld:Name>Default Styler</sld:Name>
      <sld:Title>test</sld:Title>
      <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <sld:Name>name</sld:Name>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>w</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:Within>
              <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
              <gml:Polygon>
                <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                  <gml:LinearRing>
                    <gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">51.6634,32.6499 51.6634,32.6629 51.6819,32.6629 51.6819,32.6499 51.6634,32.6499</gml:coordinates>
                  </gml:LinearRing>
                </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
              </gml:Polygon>
            </ogc:Within>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#ff0000</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
            <sld:Stroke/>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>o</sld:Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:Not>
              <ogc:Within>
                <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                <gml:Polygon>
                  <gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                    <gml:LinearRing>
                      <gml:coordinates xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">51.6634,32.6499 51.6634,32.6629 51.6819,32.6629 51.6819,32.6499 51.6634,32.6499</gml:coordinates>
                    </gml:LinearRing>
                  </gml:outerBoundaryIs>
                </gml:Polygon>
              </ogc:Within>
            </ogc:Not>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#0000ff</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
            <sld:Stroke/>
          </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
      </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </sld:UserStyle>
  </sld:NamedLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

In fact I want to have two filters. One for features inside polygon and another for outside of it.
How should I do this?

Comment: Look up the else filter in the SLD spec

Comment: Ian Turton tnx , but I couldn't find any example for it . can u take an example . I wanna show points inside polygon blue and those which are outside show red

Comment: This works fine for my test data - UK data shows up blue and US data as green - do you have some example data to show your problem,

Comment: No , I just need sld body

Comment: the SLD you have is correct - if it doesn't work as you expect I can't say why without seeing some of the data you are trying to use